# Searching and sorting in Python

Tags: python, regex, loops, if-statement, for-loop

i am writing a script in python that searches for strings and suposedly does different things when encounters strings.

```
import re, datetime
from datetime import *

f = open(raw_input('Name of file to search: ')

strToSearch = ''

for line in f:
  strToSearch += line

patFinder = re.compile('\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\sA\d{3}\sB\d{3}')
findPat1 = re.findall(patFinder, strToSearch)


# search only dates
datFinder = re.compile('\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}')
findDat = re.findall(datFinder, strToSearch)


nowDate = date.today()

fileLst = open('cels.txt', 'w')
ntrdLst = open('not_ready.txt', 'w')

for i in findPat1:
    for Date in findDat:
        Date = datetime.strptime(Date, '%d/%m/%Y')
        Date = Date.date()
        endDate = Date + timedelta(days=731)

        if endDate < nowDate:
            fileLst.write(i)
        else:
            ntrdLst.write(i)

f.close()
fileLst.close()
ntrdLst.close()

toClose = raw_input('File was modified, press enter to close: ')
```

so basically it searches for a string with dates and numbers and then same list but only dates, converts the dates, adds 2 years to each and compares, if the date surpass today's date, goes to the ntrdLst, if not, to fileLst.

My problem is that it writes the same list (i) multiple times and doesn't do the sorting.

i am fearly new to python and programming so i am asking for your help. thanks in advance

**edit: -----------------**

the normal output was this (without the date and if statement)

27/01/2009 A448 B448
22/10/2001 A434 B434
06/09/2007 A825 B825
06/09/2007 A434 B434
06/05/2010 A826 B826

what i would like is if i had a date that is after date.today() say like 27/01/2016 to write to another file and what i keep getting is the script printing this list 30x times or doesn't take to account the if statement.

(sorry, the if was indeed indented the last loop, i went wrong while putting it in here)

Comment: Isn't it just a little problem with the indentation at the last 4 lines in the for statement?


The endDate variable keeps changing, but nothing happens until it's at the last iteration of the nested for, and then it does the writing. So you're disregarding all the other dates in findDat.


Also, you might want to add an enter after writing a date object 

    `f.write(something + '\r\n')`

\r\n = enter.

Comment: @azeirah: Don't write '\r\n' unless you only want your code to work on Windows. Just write '\n' and let Python's text/universal-newlines mode deal with platform differences for you.

Comment: If you want to add 2 years, why not years=2 instead of days=731? The latter will only work when you're on a leap year boundary. And it's less readable--you have to stop and think about what 731 days means.

Comment: Finally, can you give us a small sample input and tell us the intended and actual output, instead of making us guess what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

i gave it a little (A LOT) of thought about it and just got all together in one piece. i knew that there too many for loops but now i got it. Thanks anyway to you whom have reached a helping hand to me. I leave the code for anyone having a similar problem.

```
nowDate = date.today()

for line in sourceFile:
    s = re.compile('(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s(C\d{3}\sS\d{3})')
    s1 = re.search(s, line)
    if s1:
        date = s1.group(1)
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y')
        date = date.date()
        endDate = date + timedelta(days=731)
        if endDate <= nowDate:
            fileLst.write(s1.group())
            fileLst.write('\n')
        else:
            print ('not ready: ', date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
            ntrdLst.write(s1.group(1))
            ntrdLst.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're computing endDate in a loop, once for each date... but not doing anything with it in the loop. So, after the loop is over, you have the very last endDate, and you use only that one to decide which file to write to.

I'm not sure what your logic is supposed to be, but I'm pretty sure you want to put the if statement with the writes inside the inner loop.

If you do that, then if you have, say, 100 pattern matches and 25 dates, you'll end up writing 2500 strings--some to one file, some to the other. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Not really, all the dates are related to their numbers, i just want to write some to one file and others to another based on the date that's there. if i have 100 dates with numbers i want to keep the 100 but separate them base on the date they carry. I'm sorry if i was misleading and thank you for the help.